# Android Opening Dialog Crashes App After onActivityResult

Tags: android

I have an app that scans a barcode and then opens a dialog. After the barcode is scanned with the zxing library the app then crashes. Why is this happening? This is the code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings){
            return true;
        }else if (id == R.id.action_scan){

            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();


            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


        IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanningResult != null) {
            NewPackage dialog = new NewPackage(scanningResult.getContents());
            dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "new_package_dialog");
            }
        else{

            }
        }
```

The stacktrace:

> 08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=49374, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   act=com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN flg=0x80000 (has extras) }}
>   to activity {com.example.shiptrack/com.example.shiptrack.Packages}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState 08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3351)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3394)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 08-08 12:40:32.727:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 08-08 12:40:32.727:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-08 12:40:32.727:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(22924): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1360)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1378)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.show(DialogFragment.java:138)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   com.example.shiptrack.Packages.showDialog(Packages.java:73) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   com.example.shiptrack.Packages.onActivityResult(Packages.java:63)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423) 08-08
>   12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3347)
>   08-08 12:40:32.727: E/AndroidRuntime(22924):  ... 11 more

Answer (score 1):

On Android N (7.0, released on August 2016, with more or less 25% of Android Market share), the bug is still present.

The problem is that the Activity cannot show a dialog before having handled the 
`onActivityResult`. It is not necessary to call `Activity.runOnUIThread()` because the code in `onActivityResult` already runs in the main UI thread, instead, you just have to call the parent (overridden) method `onActivityResult` before requesting the dialog  with `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);`

So your `onActivityResult` become:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // First call onActivityResult to be able to show dialogs and manage fragments.
    // If the call is not done, showing dialog will crash the app!
    // (Again, thank Google for the beautiful design)
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Do your stuff
    IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, 
        resultCode, intent);
    if (scanningResult != null) {
        NewPackage dialog = new NewPackage(scanningResult.getContents());
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "new_package_dialog");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are changing orientation while scanning bar code?
Looks like the launcher activity is getting destroyed and recreated before you get the result. 
Maybe handling configuration change for orientation and screensize in calling activity should prevent this issue.

Try adding **android:configChanges="orientation|screensize|keyboardHidden"** in activity tag of manifest.

Comment: The problem is I can get the result from the scan and put data on a textview, and I can open the dialog normally. It only seems to fail when I use it inside of onAcivityResult().